# as the day went on, the weather got worse

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Friday night was fine, and plenty of people came by, even in the dark. Saturday, **as the day went on, the weather got worse**. Rain picked up, and the weather report was threatening the coming winds. [link](https://wyrdarmouries.com/category/renaissance-festivals/)

What does "the day went on, the weather got worse" mean?

- the weather was bad since morning and was worse and worse during the day.

Or

- the weather was bad before morning and on morning it got worse.

Comment: *As the day went on* means as the hours passed. Whether the weather had been bad since (early) morning or simply worsened later is moot. It certainly deteriorated during the course of the day.

Comment: The day can also **wear on** and **drag on** or **fly by** or simply **progress**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase doesn't contain that information. You can probably infer that the weather Friday night was similar to the weather Saturday morning, and that the weather went from bad ==> good over the course of Saturday.

However, the phrase:

> as the day went on, the weather got worse

Only communicates that the weather at the end of the day, the weather was worse than at the start of the day. The weather at the start of the day could be good, or it could have been bad.